# Setting headers from main page to an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is it possible to somehow, using javascript or other methods, to set http request headers in an iframe?

Basically, i need to embed a external website into an existing webpage using an iframe. Both pages are authenticated using the same domain, and i am trying to avoid forcing the user to login twice. Both the parent webpage and the external website are running https, and they both accept the basic authentication header as login methods. So, i was thinking if there is a way to take the header from the main page, and pass it on to the iframe?

The main webpage also allows me to get the basic authentication header using javascript, so i don't need to get the header from the parent request, i just need to be able to inject a header into an iframe before loading it.

Comment: Did you figure anything out with this?

Comment: It seems that there are no generic "works-everytime" solutions. I do recall there are some headers you can set that allows sites to share headers, which might solve the problem. I'm sorry but i don't recall their names.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to modify the content of other sites through an iframe because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). A better option would be to use ajax to load the pages and then display them to the user without using an iframe.

More resources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy
- https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy

Comment: I don't understand how setting a request header violates the same-origin policy. Am i not allowed to leak headers from my main window to the iframe-based window, or how exactly should i understand this?